# Spring Boot Controller sends "Connection: close" on big body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, curl, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a Spring Boot Application (2.7.3) with a POST-Endpoint that is secured via Basic Auth. The client has reported problems connecting to the endpoint because he does use non-preemptive-authentication and receives a "Connection: close" on the first request without credentials. After receiving the Header Field, the client does not send a second request including the credentials and therefore cannot connect to the Application.

After investigation I found out that the "Connection: close" header is only send on a request with a rather large body. Is this expected behaviour?

**Curl Requests:**

```
#>curl -H "Accept: application/json" -v -d "@<path-to-file>\big_body.json" http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo/updateSapStatus
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /demo/updateSapStatus HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 1585745
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 08:01:18 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* we are done reading and this is set to close, stop send
* Closing connection 0

#>curl -H "Accept: application/json" -v -d "[]" http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo/updateSapStatus
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /demo/updateSapStatus HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 2
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 08:01:22 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

**Controller:**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/updateSapStatus")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateSapStatus(@RequestBody List<ChangeSapStatusRequestBody> requestBody) {
        return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of("Hello"));
    }
}
```

Basic Auth Configuration:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthSecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String USER = "USER";


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider basicAuthenticationProvider() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        UserDetails user = User.builder()
            .username("username")
            .password(encoder.encode("password"))
            .roles(USER)
            .build();
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userManager);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain basicAuthFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .requestMatchers(requestMatchers -> requestMatchers.anyRequest())
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().hasRole(USER))
            .csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
            .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
            .httpBasic(withDefaults())
            .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you are expection error like "bad credentials", right ?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I get a 401 "Unauthorized", but this is expected as there are no credential send on the first request.

Comment: so, what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is, that the client does not send a second request with the credentials because the connection is closed. Therefore the client cannot login with non-preemptive-authentication. When the application does not send the connection close header (on small bodys), the client can authenticate properly.